# rxjs: How to fetch related data from Firestore

Tags: firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to fetch some related data based on the values returned by an observable from Firestore.

```
getChampionshipResults(minimumCompetionCount: number): Observable<User[]> {

    const usersWithResults = this.afs.collection<User>('users')
        .valueChanges()
        .map(users => {
            return users.map(user => {
                this.afs.collection<Result>('results', ref => ref
                    .where('userUid', '==', user.uid)
                    .orderBy('position', 'asc')
                    .limit(minimumCompetionCount))
                    .valueChanges()
                    .take(1)
                    .subscribe(results => {
                        user.results = results;
                    });
                return user;
            });
        })
        .do(el => console.log(el));

    return usersWithResults;
}
```

this gives me the correct results:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwvbH.png)

But I want to do some advanced sorting / filtering on the `usersWithResults` observable. The problem is that the `user.results` property is `undefined` at the time I want to sort it:

```
getChampionshipResults(minimumCompetionCount: number): Observable<User[]> {

    const usersWithResults = this.afs.collection<User>('users')
        .valueChanges()
        .map(users => {
            return users.map(user => {
                this.afs.collection<Result>('results', ref => ref
                    .where('userUid', '==', user.uid)
                    .orderBy('position', 'asc')
                    .limit(minimumCompetionCount))
                    .valueChanges()
                    .take(1)
                    .subscribe(results => {
                        user.results = results;
                    });
                return user;
            });
        })
        .do(el => console.log(el))

        // add sorting
        .map(users => {
            return users.sort((a, b) => {

                // this is undefined
                console.log(a.results);

                // simplified dummy sort
                return 1;
            });
        });

    return usersWithResults;
}
```

I think the issue is coming from the fact that the inner observable has not completed, but I can't find the correct rxjs operator to do what I want.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.